# How can I backup a remote database schema in this environment?

Tags: oracle, backup

I have an [Oracle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database) account (schema) of a remote Oracle database. By using this account I can do all kinds of operations such as: query, update, delete and add. But I can't use exp or imp. Now my question is how can I dump all the data in this remote database schema, include table, view, function, procedure, package.

Comment: Why can't you use exp?  Not allowed? not installed? You tried but you got an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the package `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` to generate ddl for the objects.
[Read this](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/10MinuteSolution/21558/1954)

You can generate csv files for the data that you can load with sql*loader, or generate insert statements.

This will be a real pain. Especially when there is a tool available that does it for you : exp/expdp. You could try to use a local exp utility and try to connect to the remote database with it.

```
exp username/password@remotedb owner=ownername
```